# MacOS Ventura M1 mini suddenly super laggy over Screen Sharing

Tags: mac-mini, screen-sharing

Not sure what happened but a little while after upgrading to Ventura my mini "server" in the closet became super laggy over Screen Sharing. The screen will open up for input (mouse or keyboard) for 3-4 seconds every 10 seconds. It's like something is taking over and blocks all input. Tried to monitor Activity Monitor for something that's hogging resources but nothing jumps out. It's a simple media server with plex and not much else running.

Mostly hoping someone has encountered this otherwise I'll have to actually put in the work to remove it from its cozy spot in the closet and set it up with a kb and monitor. Not possible to remote in and boot into safe mode.

It appears the issue might be isolated to screensharing updating—when I perform an action that takes time and ends in an alert sound, the sound occurs and the screen draw is delayed and eventually catches up, but only momentarily.

Comment: How are you connecting to this Mac mini?  Wireless or Wired?

Comment: @Allan it's over wired

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue with a clean install of MacOS Ventura.

Unfortunately never found the root cause of this slowdown, but a hunch is that it was related to an older Migration Assistant migration, with a subsequent update to MacOS on top.